# Where was Allah when Adam and Eve were in Heaven?

Tags: practical-islam, allah, sin, jannah, adam-and-eve

I’m reading the story of Adam and Eve in chapter 7 of the Quran verses 19-22:

> “...But you and your wife, Adam, live in the Garden. Both of you eat whatever you like, but do not go near this tree or you will become wrongdoers.’ Satan whispered to them so as so to expose their nakedness, which had been hidden from them: he said, ‘Your Lord only forbade you this tree to prevent you becoming angels or immortals,’ and he swore to them, ‘I am giving you sincere advice’—he lured them with lies. Their nakedness became exposed to them when they had eaten from the tree: they began to put together leaves from the Garden to cover themselves. Their Lord called out to them, ‘Did I not forbid you forbid you to approach that tree? Did I not warn you Satan was your sworn enemy?’”

And I have a few questions:

1. Allah knew Adam and Eve will disobey Him by being lured by Shayatan, so why did He let them in paradise if he was just going to kick them out and send them down to Earth?
2. In heaven, we are told we can see Allah. Didn’t that mean Adam and Eve could see Allah? If so, why did they still fall in the trap of Shaytaan because of this? If they could see Allah, wouldn’t that mean they knew Allah would watch them disobey Him? It would have been a different story if they couldn’t see Allah. But if they could see him, Allah is everywhere so it was unlikely Allah Himself wasn’t paying attention when they went to disobey Him because He sees all.
   Would it be possible Allah didn’t look at Adam and Eve just so they would feel more inclined to disobey Allah by following Shaytaan?
3. In Islam were told we won’t sin in Jannah. So why did Adam and Eve still sin in heaven? I understand Allah was testing them, but doesn’t that go against the definition of paradise? Where one won’t sin/disobey Allah?

Comment: I suppose that these questions need some analysis and they can hardly be addressed fully in one post therefore I'd suggest you to consider splitting the post and avoid multi-question posts.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: Please ask one focused question per post. The first one is about why Allah did something and Allah does as He wishes. The remaining two are fine. As for the second one one reply is that Adam and Eve did not intentionally disobey Allah but made a mistake. For the third one the attributes of paradise apply after the day of judgement, otherwise there are many more aspects such as eternity. One view is even that this 'paradise' was a separate garden on earth and not the eternal paradise of heaven.

Comment: @UmH okay thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*2 In heaven, we are told we can see Allah. Didn’t that mean Adam and Eve could see Allah? ...*

*3 We were told we won’t sin in Jannah ...*

Arabic uses «Jannah» both for the place of the beginning of humanity and the final place after the end of time. English has this ambiguity, too, as both are often called «Paradise». English «Heaven» however only refers to the final place after the end of time.
It is certainly not pure coincidence that the two have the same naming. Both describe a state of absolute harmony with God and a desirable place. Both places are said that God Allah was or will be present, «seen». Still they are different. Only in Heaven, the future Jannah, sin is no more possible.

Using the word «place» is in the (metaphoric) image of both descriptions but it is not really a good choice to explain the meaning; in the metapher it is a place but it rather describes a (mental) state. So, in the following, I will use the word «state» instead of «place» because I think it fits better.

*1 Allah knew Adam and Eve will disobey Him*

Right. The first state of humanity would have been close to the state of an animal: Humans could not do right or wrong because they were not able to discern it. But He equipped us with the capacity to do a variety of things, to transgress or to do good and to discern good from evil. Hence, He knew that humans would disobey.

Finally, even Shaytan is *under* the law of God the Highest. God knows best.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: you're welcome. and you are very quick ;)